# vb.net - background thread issue

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

For some reason a background thread in my app can't change any labels, textbox values, etc on my main form. There is no compile errors, when the thread executes nothing happens.

Here is some example code:

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Class1
    Dim tmpThread As System.Threading.Thread

    Private Sub bgFindThread()
        Form1.lblStatus.Text = "test"
    End Sub

    Public Sub ThreadAction(ByVal Action As String)
        If Action = "Start" Then
            tmpThread = New System.Threading.Thread(New System.Threading.ThreadStart(AddressOf bgFindThread))
            tmpThread.Start()
        ElseIf Action = "Abort" Then
            If tmpThread.IsAlive = True Then tmpThread.Abort()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK code above will throw an exception IllegalCrossThreadException, it is because the background thread is not the same as UI thread and background try to set value on other thread. So windows form check every thread that work properly.
You can set Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to false to make it works.

Code below is when setting property is not run

```
Add into your code
------------------------------
Delegate Sub MyDelegate()
Private Sub RunMyControl()
  lblStatus.Text = "test"
End Sub

Change your code
------------------------------
Private Sub bgFindThread
  lblStatus.BeginInvoke (New MyDelegate(AddressOf RunMyControl))
End Sub
```

The method asyncronsly run code from background thread to UI thread.

Comment: The execption is only thrown when running in the debugger.  Setting CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to false is evil!

Comment: This answer didn't solve my problem but it did put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access UI controls from the UI thread.

I suggest reading this first: http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: The link is good in general but it doesn’t explain how to properly update UI elements from a different thread.

Comment: @Konrad Got to start somewhere!

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, it is forbidden (for good reasons) to update UI elements from a non-UI thread.

The canonical solution is as follows:

- Test whether you are outside the UI thread
- If so, request for an operation to be performed inside the UI thread
- [Inside the UI thread] Update the control.

In your case:

```
Private Sub bgFindThread()
    If lblStatus.InvokeRequired Then
        lblStatus.Invoke(New Action(AddressOf bgFindThread))
        Return
    End If

    lblStatus.Text = "test"
End Sub
```

The only thing that changed is the guard clause at the beginning of the method which test whether we’re inside the UI thread and, if not, requests an execution in the UI thread and returns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a delegate to update UI controls in a background thread.

Example

```
Private Delegate Sub bkgChangeControl(ByVal bSucceed As Boolean)
Private dlgChangeControl As bkgChangeControl = AddressOf ChangeControl

Private Sub threadWorker_ChangeControl(ByVal bSucceed As Boolean)
    Me.Invoke(dlgChangeControl, New Object() {bSucceed})
End Sub  
     Private Sub ChangeControl()
     Me.lable="Changed"
     End Sub
      'In your background thread, call threadWorker_ChangeControl.
```